# Generate reports using Clang Analyzer - scan-build

Tags: ios, clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang++

I am new to Clang analyzer and I am trying to generate reports using scan-build. While using the scan-build as below:

```
./scan-build --use-analyzer=/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang -v  -o report_location sample.xcodeproj
```

I am always getting the below error:

```
scan-build: Using `/build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang' for static analysis ; Can't exec "sample.xcodeproj": 
Permission denied at ./scan-build line 1029. ;
scan-build: Removing directory 'report_location/2013-06-25-1' because it contains no reports. ;
scan-build: No bugs found.
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way scan build works is it either

1. invokes the command you provide e.g. `make`
2. executes the file that you provide e.g. some shell script

And when it does that it overrides the $CC environment variable to point to another script from where it forks two processes. In one the compiler runs as regular build and in another static-analyzer runs to generate report.

You are getting this error because 'sample.xcodeproj' is not an executable.
I'm not very familiar with `xcode` but I think if you `chmod +x sample.xcodeproj` then things should work.

clang-static analyzer can be integrated with xcode as well:

http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/000-About_Xcode/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW17